# Identation Error

Tags: python

i have the error that says "IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level", i have tried using the commands and changing the space and tabs but still, the error continues appearing, and i have tried all i have read in the forums but the error still appearing on the same part, please help
error part:
bullets.update()
               ^
code:

```
    def update_bullets(bullets):
"""Update position of bullets and gets rid of old bullets"""
#Update bullet position
 bullets.update()

# Get rid of bullets that had dissapeared
    for bullet in bullets.copy():
        if bullet.rect.bottom <= 1:
            bullets.remove(bullet)
        print(len(bullets))
```

Comment: Indentation in python will be covered in any tutorial.

Comment: In Python, white space is relevant. Your indentation is all over the place, and that will never work. You can find a Python tutorial at http://python.org

Comment: The role of indentation is almost certainly the first lesson in any Python textbook or tutorial. How is it possible to learn the language without knowing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code, properly indented, should look like this:

```
def update_bullets(bullets):
"""Update position of bullets and gets rid of old bullets"""
    #Update bullet position
    bullets.update()

    # Get rid of bullets that had dissapeared
    for bullet in bullets.copy():
        if bullet.rect.bottom <= 1:
            bullets.remove(bullet)
        print(len(bullets))
```

Python code requires proper indentation at all times. Whitespace matters (unlike C)!

I would recommend checking out [this tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_basic_syntax.htm) for a basic tutorial on Python.

Comment: @KenWhite Fair enough, I have elaborated on my answer.